# Is there a missing variable in the double slit experiment?

Tags: visible-light, double-slit-experiment, models

I've been reviewing the double slit experiment lately and I believe it is missing a few crucial things. Thickness of the wall is my primary focus. How could I add thickness into the equation? I'm interested in seeing the effect on a model.

Comment: That might affect the near-field interference pattern, but I don't think it will affect the far-field pattern. What do you mean by "crucial"?  Do you mean that these properties are necessary for *precise, quantitative* predictions, or do you mean that including these properties will affect fundamental, *qualitative* features of the double-slit pattern?  If it's the former, sure, of course. If it's the latter, then not really.

Comment: What is stopping you from modeling this?